# Duvida com uso de `pthread` em posix

Tags: c, thread, unix, posix

Estou usando a seguinte rotina com comando da biblioteca `pthread.h`:

```
//
//  Declaração
//
pthread_t       threads[NUM_THREADS];

//
//  Criacao
//
for(...)
{
    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL,   MainTH,     (void *)    &thread_args[i]);
}

//
//  execução 
//
for(...)
{
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
}
```

Dessa forma elas não trabalham de forma independentes, certo?
aguardam para a terminação da outra `Thread`

queria saber, como faco para trabalhar com elas de forma separada, independentes?

Answer (score 0):

O código me parece correto.
A função pthread_create inicia a execução da thread sem bloqueio, ou seja, a thread passa a executar sem interromper o fluxo principal.
Por fim, a função pthread_join aguarda a finalização de todas as threads. Essa bloqueia o fluxo principal para que cada thread seja finalizada uma a uma.

Comment: sim, mas somente retirar esse função vai fazer que elas trabalhem de forma independentes, não ocorrerá  do programa fechar já que o main não aguardará as threads e entra chegar ao fim?